# Stop element scroll when use UP/DOWN key in jquery and Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript code which navigate to next/previous element using UP or DOWN key:

```
$(function(){
    var $p = $(".test p");

    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        var $elementToBeSelected = $p.filter(function() { return $(this).hasClass("active"); }).first();
        if(!$elementToBeSelected.length){
            $elementToBeSelected = $p.first();
        }

        $p.removeClass("active");

        // if is down
       if(e.which ===  40){
           if($elementToBeSelected.next().length){
              $elementToBeSelected = $elementToBeSelected.next();   
           }
       } else {
           if($elementToBeSelected.prev().length){
              $elementToBeSelected = $elementToBeSelected.prev();   
           }          
       }

        $elementToBeSelected.addClass("active");
        $(".test").scrollTo($elementToBeSelected, 200);
    });
});
```

and HTML part:

```
<div class="test">
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
    <p>asdasdasdada</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>dasdasdasd</p>
</div>
```

Or better, see: http://jsfiddle.net/4u81tgmd/

In Firefox, when click inside container (which has paragraphs) and navigate up/down, it looks fine.

In Chrome, some flickering happens to scrollbar.

It is happens when you click inside div with paragraphs and try to press up/down and browser automatically move you depends on what key you pressed.

How to prevent it ? How to use only `scrollTo` event you clicked on that container to works in all browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.preventDefault()

[**MDN Refenrence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> Event.preventDefault() Cancels the event if it is cancelable, without
>   stopping further propagation of the event.

[**working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bnmkewxs/)

```
$(function(){
    var $p = $(".test p");

    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        var $elementToBeSelected = $p.filter(function() { return $(this).hasClass("active"); }).first();
        if(!$elementToBeSelected.length){
            $elementToBeSelected = $p.first();
        }

        $p.removeClass("active");

        // if is down
       if(e.which ===  40){
           if($elementToBeSelected.next().length){
              $elementToBeSelected = $elementToBeSelected.next();   
           }
       } else {
           if($elementToBeSelected.prev().length){
              $elementToBeSelected = $elementToBeSelected.prev();   
           }          
       }

        $elementToBeSelected.addClass("active");
        $(".test").scrollTo($elementToBeSelected, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: I totally forgot `preventDefault` for keydown event

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
return false;
```

if you have processed the key.